# String append in java

Tags: java, java-8, null, stringbuilder

I am constructing single string value based on some other string details, which is as below.
But don't wants to add if any of DTO value is null or empty. How can I add it in java.

```
String dummyVal = new StringBuffer ("<b> test Id </b> ").append(someDTO.getId()).append(", ")
.append("<b> Type: </b> ").append(someDTO.getType()).append(", ")
.append("<b> Date: </b> ").append(someDTO.getDate()).toString();

sysout(dummyVal);
```

Actual result is :

```
<b>test Id:</b> 123, <b>Type:</b> pend, <b>Date:</b> xx/yy/zz
```

### EXAMPLE: id - 123 , type - pend, date - null

Expected result is like:

```
<b>test Id:</b> 123, <b>Type:</b> pend
```

Need to ignore the null value tags and to add only tags is not null in java string.

Then Expected result is like:

```
<b>test Id:</b> 123, <b>Type:</b> pend
```

Comment: you should perform a null check on each of the variables before you append it to your stringbuffer or stringbuilder

Comment: .append("<b> Date: </b>") -> could you please explain how you think this would/could be dependent on a value that's not even part of this append?

Comment: `StringBuffer` has been superseded by `StringBuilder` in Java 5. But you don’t need to replace `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder`, you get it for free when you just write `String dummyVal = "<b> test Id </b> " + someDTO.getId() + ", " + "<b> Type: </b> " + someDTO.getType() + ", " + "<b> Date: </b> " + someDTO.getDate() + ", "`; In fact, the code generated for the simple expression using `+` will be even better.

Comment: @Holger is there some source you could provide on that? I remember reading about it, but i recall that the optimization of the string concats is not guaranteed as it may or may not use the stringbuilder.

Comment: Once you have your null check in place, you may want to look into a `StringJoiner`. It can put `", "` *between* your items and does not put it after the last one, which may be convenient for your situation.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X the specification does indeed [not require it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1:~:text=An%20implementation%20may,to%20a%20string.) but it’s a matter of fact that Java compilers use such an optimization since 1.0 (using `StringBuffer` prior to Java 5 and `StringBuilder` afterwards or `StringConcatFactory` when using `javac` with JDK 9+). There never was a compiler not optimizing string concatenation in such way in the last quarter century.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how conditions are used when using the `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilders` in Java applications.
Rewritten your snippet here with conditions.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer ("<b> test Id </b> ").append(someDTO.getId());

if(Objects.nonNull(someDTO.getType())) {
    buffer.append(", ").append("<b> Type: </b> ").append(someDTO.getType());
}
if(Objects.nonNull(someDTO.getDate())) {
    buffer.append(", ").append("<b> Date: </b> ").append(someDTO.getDate());
}
//buffer.setLength(buffer.length() - 1); // this is updated as per Holger's comment
String dummyValue = buffer.toString();
```

Comment: Don’t write `Objects.nonNull(…)` when you can simply write `null != …` Further, there is no “last extra semicolon”. This code is using `", "` as separator, which is not only a comma+space, not a semicolon, but also *two* chars, so you have to use `buffer.setLength(buffer.length() - 2);` to remove the last separator.

Comment: @Holger I would myself write `someDTO.getType() != null`. I certainly prefer the clear and natural `Objects.nonNull(someDTO.getType())` over the backward `null != someDTO.getType()`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I just placed the `null` at the beginning, because I replaced the answer’s construct and kept the `…` at the same position. I’d also prefer `someDTO.getType() != null`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, I also agree. Although many people would say it's for using in predicates but when you static import it, the code becomes more readable than using operators.

Comment: @AnkitWasankar Thanks for sharing your view. I will leave that as a matter of taste. I can live happily with my colleagues writing either.

Comment: By the way way, you don’t need to remove an extra separator via `setLength` when you don’t add it in the first place. Instead of having an `.append(", ")` each of the three parts, just have an `.append(", ")` at the beginning of each of the two optional parts.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to archive this. Here is a example with Java Optionals and Streams.

```java
import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;

// ...

var result = Stream.of(
      ofNullable(someDTO.getId()).map(x -> "<b> test Id </b> " + x),
      ofNullable(someDTO.getType()).map(x -> "<b> Type: </b> " + x),
      ofNullable(someDTO.getDate()).map(x -> "<b> Date </b> " + x)
    )
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```

Now it is very readable.

Comment: [`String.format(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) is a `static` method so you can’t write `"<b> test Id </b> %s"::format` Maybe, you meant [`"<b> test Id </b> %s"::formatted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) but it’s very inefficient, compared to a simple `x -> "<b> test Id </b> %s" + x`. Since `formatted` requires at least Java 15, you can also use `Stream.ofNullable(…)` and `Stream.concat(…)` without `Optional`.

Comment: Of course, I meant `x -> "<b> test Id </b> " + x` without the need for placeholders that have to be parsed at runtime…

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I like the `.formatted()`-method, because the type doesn't matter.  `someDTO.getDate()` can return a `ZonenDateTime` and it still works. I will later check `Stream.ofNullable(...)` and `Stream.concat(...)` idea, it sounds interesting.

Comment: That’s why I didn’t suggest `"<b> test Id </b> "::concat` because that only works for strings. But `x -> "<b> test Id </b> " + x` works for any type.

Comment: I played around and `Stream.ofNullable()` and `Stream.concat()` is not so cool because `Stream.concat()` only works for two streams. And it is slower (also with `.flatMap()`). But using `+`-operator is indeed faster than `formatted()` and still usable for different types. I will change my answer. Thanks for the input.